# How can I convert a list of tuples into a mask?

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

- Imagine that I have a numpy array of shape (720, 1280):

  `grid = np.zeros((720, 1280))`
- And then I have a list of tuples that looks like this:

  `x_y_pairs_to_activate = [(241, 623), (390, 143), (313, 406)]`

How can I convert that list of tuples into a mask so that I activate the respective coordinates?

```
grid[x_y_pairs_to_activate] = 1 # something like that
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transpose your coordinates list so that you have all the first-coordinates in one list and all the second-coordinates in another list.

```
x_coords = [c[0] for c in x_y_pairs_to_activate]
y_coords = [c[1] for c in x_y_pairs_to_activate]
grid[x_coords, y_coords] = 1
```

Or in more "numpythonic" language

```
mask = np.array(x_y_pairs_to_activate).transpose()
grid[mask] = 1
```

Comment: The "numpythonic" way didn't work for me; but the first one did. Thanks!

Comment: no worries, why didn't it work for you ? it really is the better way